# Attitude of Bernie and Clinton supporters towards Trump

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, donald-trump, hillary-clinton, bernie-sanders

Is there a comparison of what attitude self-identified Bernie supporters have towards Donald Trump compared to what attitude self-identified Hillary Clinton supporters have towards Donald Trump? Are supporters of one candidate more likely to report a favourable opinion of Trump than the other candidate?

Answer (score 5):

As it happens FiveThirtyEight [just posted](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/sanderss-endorsement-may-help-among-his-most-anti-clinton-supporters/) an analysis of Sander's endorsement of Clinton, which includes a breakdown of poll results on a closely related question.

[image: Sanders supporters more likely to back Clinton without third-party candidates]

I haven't seen any polls which ask Sanders supporters about favorable/unfavorable status, but voting preferences make a good proxy.

The third parties in question are Gary Johnson and Jill Stein for two of the surveys.  Stein was not an option in the Pew poll.

Comment: what's the third party in that scenario?

Comment: @blip - Added that information.  Thanks for asking.